Issue with Flavors in Multi-Dimensional Project Configuration
I'm trying to add multiple flavors to my project based on three dimensions: Locale, Env, and Os. I tried creating flavor directories by combining two dimensions, like Locale+Env and Env+Os, but this doesn't work when I select a flavor. It seems I need to create directories that combine all three dimensions together for the project to link properly.

